# Ultimately, what will the Physics Stack Exchange Become? Are there long term goals?

Tags: discussion, scope, policy

It was sometime back that I realized what we are synthesizing here (possibly) is an **archive** for an expert system. Put the Physics Stack Exchange together with an AI machine and you have a super-physicist. The same might be said of other Stack areas, knowledge bases.

What will the stack eventually become? Are there longer term goals than to just ask/answer questions?

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1096/2451 , http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/5173/2451

Comment: world domination! Just like _Skynet_:P

Comment: *"Put the Physics Stack Exchange together with an AI machine and you have a super-physicist.*"  Really?  I'm not convinced.

Comment: Like what @Dirk Bruere said, we already have one from @Qmechanic! :)

Comment: Some very capable but controversial people have left the site. Personally, I'm more active on SO, and some of my posts are either very controversial or simply not understood, in spite of my efforts to explain. Some people need a thick skin to stay on sites like this, though it is a "society" of sorts. It's kind of boring when I get no comments, even if they're negative. BTW, I got a PhD in AI, and you have more faith in it than I do. It's kinda rested on its laurels the last 2-3 decades, Siri/Google notwithstanding.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Eventually what it will become is a place where anyone who asks any question will be referred to a previous answer before their question is closed down.

Comment: That is an interesting perspective, but it suggests that there will be a point that physics will not have anything new to discover & I'm not quite willing to concede that point.

Comment: A fool can ask more questions than ten wise men can answer...

Comment: @Dirk Bruere: Ironically, this may happen to this meta post itself.

Comment: @Floris Isn't that why they call them fools? (See another question )

Comment: Seriously I see allot of value in the sense we are collectively building an immense data base.

Comment: Mind you that Stack Exchange has quite a lead on us in the total number of questions asked and they haven't reach that asymptote yet. Could take a while.

Comment: Yeah, thought experiment might suggest that. But on stack overflow, we have a question about someone's AJAX request not sending data to PHP script **[every few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax+php)**. So nope, this is not going to happen.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Although the cutting edge physics questions are not posed by amateurs but rather people with a stronger background than 99% of the user-base. So the only thing that's left is clarification questions about confusing news-articles *about* new physics.

Comment: I'm dying of laughing after reading this

Answer (score 3):

Humans will cease to exist within a few generations, they'll be replaced by machines. It's likely that our civilization will give rise to one superintelligence, all knowledge acquired by us will be absorbed by it. Digital records are then more useful than paper records, so the files stored on servers containing the contents of this site may make it into the brains of this superintelligence. A lot of the content will likely be interpreted as examples of how primitive biological beings approach physics problems.

Comment: So then food for the gods

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-30290540 It's better to just accept the inevitable, work on the basis of realistic assumptions. We are not going to be around for very long, whatever we write here will only be read by humans for a few generations and then it will be accessible for potentially billions of years to machine civilizations.

Comment: Yes, let's all take the opinion of someone who's seen *Terminator* one too many times.

Comment: We are the Borg. You will be assimilated. Resistance is futile. :P

Comment: @Danu I thought the original question is a joke as well.

Comment: +1 if a joke. -1 if not.

Comment: @innisfree It's either along the lines of what I wrote (a rather optimistic view of the future) or [something along these lines](https://profhugodegaris.wordpress.com/how-will-the-artilect-war-start/).

Comment: @Count Iblis: It seems many think against this. But I agree on your statement. This is not a joke & after all, who saw the future? Just one upvote of mine & I'm really eager to watch when a real _Skynet_ comes & consumes these data to become  _REAL_ physicist.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Dirk Bruere. Although I hardly post here, on any site you will have

- homework with some solution attempts, so probably worth giving a particularized answer. Sending the asker to a different problem/example is not that different from telling him to RTFM. And there's an inexhaustible number of homework problems.
- tumbleweed questions that usually are too hard to [actually] answer. My SO questions are mostly like that. Well, I get some answers, but it's usually not what I asked... more like extended comments. A small percentage of these will probably get an actual answer over time.

These two issues are [actually connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/885618/g%C3%B6dels-incompleteness-theorems).

Comment: Do notice that we don't allow people to post arbitrary homework problems, and that frames as conceptual question there are simply fewer version and things can be closed as duplicates fairly often.

Comment: @dmckee: I don't see how [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216377/gravitational-binding-energy-of-2d-circle) is any different from arbitrary HW, to pick an example just from the 1st page.

Comment: And even ignoring that, the number of ways someone can misunderstand some [formula](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216395/parallel-connection-of-capacitor) or  [proof](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/216384/issues-with-the-proof-of-the-no-cloning-theorem) is probably limitless as well.

Comment: HW is assuredly considered off topic here, however the problem we face is that we need 5 members with >3k rep to vote to close and it always seems to be [the same ~10 members](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/history) voting day in & day out. It's an issue of too many crap questions and too few voters.

Answer (score -4):

I would love to see this kind of website evolve into a new place where research may be published and reviewed. Voters and answerers would be the referees, and their *reputation* may indicate the strength of their votes.

Comment: That would be an odd member of the StackExchange family of Q&A sites. And what would be the correct answer to accept anyway? Besides, isn't this what arxiv is for?

Comment: The last half of the last sentence has been discussed numerous times in different SE sites and is rejected each time in favor of *the democratic system*, as opposed to the *plutarchy system* you are describing.