# Why close an answered question when both answer and question have positive vote counts?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Especially when a user cannot delete their own question.

Comment: Votes and on-topicness are not directly related - the people voting to close can be different people than the people upvoting things. Are you asking about a specific question?

Comment: I think that is a problem and conflicts with the idea of keeping a Q&A when the author wants to delete it.

Comment: Note that deleting a question also deletes its answers. The author of a question doesn’t have the right to delete upvoted answers by other users.

Comment: Its not possible to close or remove answers that add no value to the Q&A and clearly shows a lack of effort, but its possible to delete questions by contributors that are open to changing their question to fit the rules of the site. This is a problem in my opinion.

Comment: An example of the situation would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Broadly speaking, closing a question is not usually an instantaneous thing (and rightly so) so it is entirely possible that, during the time a question accumulates the required number of votes to close, other users upvote or even answer the question.  In fact I would not be surprised if à faire fraction closed questions had some votes (up or down) and/or some answers (also with votes).

One perfectly legitimate reason to close an upvoted question with an upvoted answer is duplication.  Failure to close will eventually generate huge amounts of repetition and will make the site difficult to search.

Closing a question should not be a race, and neither should up- or downvoting.  As a result, I do not think that up-voted questions with answers should be immune from closure.

Of course it is also my experience that many posters fail to properly search the site for duplicates or near duplicates, or fail to understand that direct homework questions are off-topic.  There are many other examples where the natural delay built in the closing mechanism is likely longer than the time it takes to cast an upvote or write a simple answer.

Comment: *Failure to close will eventually generate huge amounts of repetition and will make the site difficult to search.* Of course, [eventually all questions will be closed as duplicates of a previous question.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7183/25301)

Comment: @KyleKanos ‘nice to “see” you again.